# Fast patch extraction using homography

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, homography

Suppose you have an homography H relating a planar surface depicted in two different images, Ir and I. Ir is the reference image, where the planar surface is parallel to the image plane (and practically occupy the entire image). I is a run-time image (a photo of the planar surface taken at an arbitrary viewpoint). Let H be such that:

> p = Hp', where p is a point in Ir and p' is the corresponding point in I.

Suppose you have two points p1=(x1,y) and p2=(x2,y), with x1 < x2, relative to the image Ir. Note that they belong to the same row (common y). Let H'=H^(-1). Using H', you can compute the corresponding points in I of the following points: (x1,y),(x1+1,y),...,(x2,y).

The question is: is there a way to avoid the matrix-vector multiplication to compute all those points? The easiest way that comes to me is to use the homography to compute the corresponding point of p1 and p2 (call them p1' and p2'). To obtain the others (that is: (x1+1,y), (x1+2,y),...,(x2-1, y)), linear interpolate p1' and p2' in the image I.

But since there is a projective transformation between Ir and I, i think that this method is quite imprecise.

Any other idea? This question is relative to the fact that i need a computational efficient way to extract a lot of (small) patches (of around 10x10 pixels) around a point p in Ir in a real-time software.

Thank you.

Ps.
Maybe the fact that i am using smal patches would make using linear interpolation a suitable approach?

Answer (score 0):

You have a *projective transform* and, unfortunately, *ratio of lengths are not invariant* under this type of transformation.

My suggestion: explore the [cross ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio) because it is invariant under projective transformations. I think that for each 3 points you can get a "cheaper" 4th, avoiding the matrix-vector computation and using the cross ratio instead. But I have not put all the stuff in paper to verify if the cross ratio alternative is that much "computationally cheaper" than the matrix-vector multiplication.